# Usability: Do mac users understand "right-click"?

Tags: macos, usability

I have a feature of my application which depends on alternate-click. Windows users don't understand "alternate-click" though, and I was wondering if most mac users understood "right-click", and if so if they were offended or annoyed when they see such text.

Does anyone have experience developing usable (consumer) applications for mac users? Does anyone have any opinions on this?

Comment: You're right about something :) I'm a linux user, former windows user, former amiga user, former ... etc. Well it's the first time ever I hear the expression "alternate click".

Comment: Isn't it funny that there seem to be at least 4 names for the right click on mac where everything is said to be more unified? Anyways, i'd simply use "right-click", most if not all Mac users will be used to that term and use the correct mouse button (Or you change the application so that the behaviour can be produced with a left click)

Comment: The problem is "right-click" is that it's only one way to generate secondary click (in the case of a two-button mouse, control-click being the other), may not generate the secondary click (if the buttons have been reversed), and may not even be possible (for a one-button mouse). On a trackpad, "right-click" is not what you mean at all. The confusion has generally come as more Windows users and developers have come to Mac, and brought the "right-click" term with them (and are unfamiliar with other terms). Even on Windows, this is confusing because you can swap the buttons.

Comment: Semantically, it may be wrong, but I think lefties and swappers will have adapted to poor wording by this point. Don't you?

Comment: I agree that lefties have (though it's still confusing on a single-button mouse). Non-English speakers have adapted to UIs that are only in English, but we fix that. We should be user-centric here. That also means we should look for words and phrases that are both accurate and clear, not just technically correct (which can be even more confusing). The best approach is to limit how much documentation is needed. You shouldn't need to *tell* the user that clicking does something. If you do have to, it's best to explain how to achieve "right click," since it is not always obvious on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X calls it **secondary click**, although the term ["right click"](https://www.apple.com/mac/) is visible even in Apple's documentation.

[image]
<sub>(source: [macinstruct.com](http://www.macinstruct.com/new/images/columns/mouse8.jpg))</sub>

Comment: The secondary click terminology is specific to laptops and other machines with trackpads. It is also used with Apple's new Magic Mouse. Regular Mac users are unlikely to have come across the term and, as such, would strongly recommend against its use until it becomes more common and makes it into the "Apple Publications Style Guide". You may consider heading over to http://bugreport.apple.com and reporting this terminology confusion.

Comment: Before we had the hardware to do a secondary click it used to be a ctrl+click (or a long click if one installed a little extension (called finder pop i believe, back in the OS 8 days). The only places where I've ever seen the term "right click" is where the document was meant for windows users. Right click is also just stupid, ask left handed people.

Comment: I know a few lefties who still use their right-hand for mice. Most (good) mice are right-hand specific.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you ease it out and create two different texts displayed for the two different systems?

Comment: I would, but I'd rather just change a translated string than make a new string, add logic, and have all 2*n translations created.

Comment: Having the right text to display for the correct system in my opinion is more "professional" or customer tailored, but I get your point, you can always settle with the first answer (by Justin), is it feasible?

Answer (score 3):

The definitive publication for the correct Mac OS X terminology is the "Apple Publications Style Guide". At this time, the latest was published in September 2008 can be found at:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/APStyleGuide/APSG_2008.pdf 
or
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/#section=Topics&topic=User%20Experience

I could find no mention of "secondary click" or "right click".

In this case, what should be used is "control-click".

Comment: *"Control-click"* among Windows users is most likely going to be interpreted as pressing down the `Ctrl` key and then left-clicking.

Comment: @Esko: That is indeed what it refers to. That's the traditional way of bringing up a contextual menu, because Macs traditionally did not have right mouse buttons.

Comment: @Esko Yep. Which is why one needs different text depending on what users are going to be reading it.

Answer (score 2):

Wait, why are you making the user right click? This isn't The Mac Way

Edit: Assuming you're doing it correctly (not only providing the menu item on the contextual menu), I think there's precedence, in the Apple Human Inteface Guidelines for calling it "Contextual Menu"

Comment: Not so at all. Control-click (which maps to the right-click or "secondary click") is a venerable feature of Mac with long history and wide usage. They are very much "The Mac Way" as long as the menu presented applies specifically to the selected object. The use of a second button to provide faster access to this feature is newer, but concept is well established since the MacOS days.

Comment: Ok. The Apple HIGs (http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGMenus/XHIGMenus.html) say:

"Always ensure that contextual menu items are also available as menu commands. A contextual menu is hidden by default and a user might not know it exists, so it should never be the only way to access a command. In particular, you should not use a contextual menu as the only way to access an advanced or power-user feature."

So you shouldn't MAKE your users right click, but if you're good that way, then yes control-clicking is established.

Comment: @Rob Napier: Control-click has existed for a long time, but *making* the user control-click to get some functionality goes against a very long-standing Apple guideline.

Comment: @Chuck, see Ryan's comment. OP never suggests this would be the only access to the functionality. He simply is asking what to call the action.

Comment: @Rob Napier: Eh, "a feature … which depends on alternate-click" suggests that it requires right-clicking.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't depend on alternate-click. It's just another way to get to the same functionality. Whether or not there should be two ways to skin the same sheep, however, is another usability concern, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Secondary click is not enabled by default, meaning Control + Click is required to bring up the Contextual Menu. Bizarrely the side buttons that activate Expose are enabled by default.

Even if the user is aware of right click, the design of the Apple mouse often leads them to think the mouse can't right click.

There will be a significant number of users (ie designers) that don't use a mouse at all because they just use a graphics tablet. I had a rather frustrating call with my dad the other day and it turns out he hadn't used a mouse in 8 years!